# Flatten a mask group in Figma

Tags: mask, figma, outline

So I have made myself some striped bars for a histogram by creating the desired stripes and applying the bars as a mask to it like described [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/157593/163908), which looks like this:

[image: Histogram]

Now I would like to add an outline to those bars. But if I add an outline to the original bars, the masked area just gets wider.

So I would like to flatten this mask group. Sort of applying the pattern to my bars. But then the bars as well as the pattern are combined into a vector without the masking applied:

[image: Flattened]

How can I get rid of the mask group and still keep the effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

1. Select and duplicate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the object which is being used as the mask.
2. Drag it to the top of the layers, ungroup, and then group it again.
3. Remove the fill, and add a stroke.

An Example

[image]